# Gmail one account to other account data transfer easiest way

Tags: gmail

Can anyone help me to copy my one gmail account data,mails and drive content to another account

Comment: Is this the right place to ask this ?

Comment: In My point of view stack overflow is place to know about unknown things.So Am asking this question.I believe here only I can got  answer.Lots of experienced peoples here.

Comment: Look here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88X1JNKFQVA

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/56283?hl=en

Comment: Thank You So Much !